# Dynamicaly created html not rendering in screen

Tags: jquery, dynamic

In my application, I am listing all products available in that shop. For that, I am doing loop product array. In between checking customer

already added that product to his cart or not. If he already added I want to give two buttons +, -  to add or minus product from cart else I am giving one button to Add to cart.

For that, I am looping one more array that contained the product he added to the cart. But here my problem is buttons not rendering to screen and no error also.
When I do debug it's going to those parts as expected. But these those buttons not showing, remaining HTML rendering as expected. Below giving my code

```
$.each(obj, function (key, value) {

ProductHtml += "<div id=divParenList" + value.Id + ";>"
          + "<span id = spnProdListProdName" + value.Id + ">" + value.ProductName + "</span> "
          + "<span id = spnProdListBarnd" + value.Id + ">" + value.Brand + "</span>"
          + "<span id = spnProdListPrice" + value.Id + ">" + value.Price + "</span> <br>"
          + "<span id = spnProdListQty" + value.Id + " > <input type=text id=txtProdListQty" + value.Id + 
             "  /></span> <br>"
           $.each(CartArray, function (Index, Cartvalue) {
            if (parseInt(Cartvalue.Id) == value.Id) {
                           console.log(" product available")
                + "<input type=button id=btnAddProduct-" + value.Id + " value = + onClick =  ChangeQty(value.Id, BookedQty)/>"
                +"<input type=button id=btnReduceProduct-" + value.Id + " value =-  onClick =  ChangeQty(value.Id, BookedQty) />"
                    } else {
               + "<input type=button id=btnAddCart-" + value.Id + " value = Add onClick = AddToCart(this.id) />"
                           console.log("no product")    }
                })
                    + "<input type=hidden id=hdnProdListProductId" + value.Id + " value = " + value.Id + " />"
            + "</div > ";
         })
```